# Suppress display of Table fields in HTML / ASP.NET

Tags: html, asp.net, angularjs

I inherited a web app built in ASP.NET which returns a table of query results which pull from a database. Right now, all fields display as text, with the exception of the "Url" column which is a hyperlink (as seen in below code).  What code would I add if I wanted to also suppress the display of one of the columns returned (or just not return it at all if that makes more sense)?

EDIT - additional information:  the table columns are not pre-defined anywhere in the source code.  The app has the ability for you to define a database and table from which to pull the results of your query - therefore the resulting table is dynamic.  This is why it seems it has to be done in the HTML code of the page itself.

Below is the HTML code for the table:

```
<div class="row" ng-if="loading || results != null">
    <div class="col-lg-2" ng-show="facets">
        <div class="widget">
            <div class="widget-title">
                <i class="fa fa-check-square-o"></i> Facets
            </div>
            <div class="widget-body xlarge no-padding">
                <pre>{{ facets | json }}</pre>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div ng-class="{ 'col-lg-10': facets != null, 'col-lg-12': facets == null }">
        <div class="widget">
          <div class="widget-title">
                <i class="fa fa-bars"></i> Results <span>({{ count }} results)</span>
            </div>
            <div class="widget-body xlarge no-padding">
                <div class="message" ng-if="!loading && (results == null || results.length == 0)">
                    <div class="alert alert-warning">The query did not return any results.</div>
                </div>
                <div class="table-responsive" ng-if="!loading && results != null && results.length > 0">
                    <table class="table table-hover">
                        <thead>
                            <tr>
                                <th ng-repeat="field in fields">
                                    {{field}}
                                </th>
                            </tr>
                        </thead>
                        <tbody>

                            <tr ng-repeat="result in results">
                                <td ng-repeat="field in fields">
                                    <div ng-if="field == 'Url'">
                                        <a href="{{ result.Url }}"> {{ result.DirectSourceUrl }}</a>
                                    </div>
                                    <div ng-if="field !== 'Url'">
                                        {{ result[field] }}
                                    </div>
                                </td>

                            </tr>
                        </tbody>
                    </table>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

I am not a .NET expert but i do know angular so if i get your question right, just ignore the field you wanna delete and don't bind it in the html or you could do something like this in angular controller right after the results are returned response.data.fieldName=undefined; (fieldName is the name off the column you wanna delete.

Hope it helped you.

Comment: Hi Souhail, the problem is that the field names are not defined anywhere in the code.  It's returning a table based on a selected table of a database.  I will edit my question in this regard.

Comment: so you wanna delete something and you don't know what it is??

Comment: No, of course this is not the case.  In your suggestion you say to use fieldName as the name of the column.  But the program does not know the names of the fields because it doesn't have any idea what table it's returning until its returned.  Or are you saying that I can still use this object and the angular controller will find that column name AFTER the table is returned, and possibly be able to suppress it from display?

Comment: yes you can manipulate it with angular, but still you need to know the names of the object to be deleted or at lest some indicator like the level of the object in question or any thing to identify your object

Comment: Ok understood. Let me take a look inside the angular code.

Comment: let me know what you find out :)

Comment: The code inside the angular controller is a mess.  I can't read any of it due to the format.  I am opening a new thread about the formatting as soon as my 90 minute delay is up.

Comment: didn't you write it? is it minified ?

Comment: No I didn't write it, I inherited it from a prior developer.  Yes, it has been minified, this is exactly the issue.  Is there any way to format it back for easy reading in Visual Studio 2015?

Comment: you can use this online tool http://jsbeautifier.org/ but i dont think it will help you much because the minified version change most of the variables names

Comment: Yes I just found that tool. And you're correct, the variables can't be restored now.  It seems I'm going to have to re-build this from scratch to get the table format that I need.  Thanks for your attention.